# FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql

Есть бэкенд, работающий на PHP и база данных - PostgreSQL. На сервере реализован механизм хранения снапшотов - снимков страниц. Исходный код страниц хранится в таблице в базе данных. В момент запроса поисковых роботов алгоритм проверяет, как давно был сделан снапшот и если с этого момента прошло более недели, то он изымает из базы данных необходимый html-код и отдаёт его роботу. На это уходит не более 100 миллисекунд. В последние два дня заметил, что Яндекс начал долбить мой сервер запросами. За сегодня уже отсканировал более 15000 страниц, однако сервер время от времени уходил в таймаут на 3-5 минут. Позднее я зашёл в логи PHP, чтобы понять, что вообще происходит. Там вижу ошибку:

> 2018/08/10 19:45:46 [error] 15045#15045: *116389 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
>
> FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode in /var/www/production/engine/functions.php on line 18

Пошёл в логи PostgreSQL и там такая картина:

> 2018-08-10 19:45:41.101 CEST [15563] flaut@flaut_db DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
>
> 2018-08-10 19:45:41.101 CEST [15563] flaut@flaut_db HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
>
> 2018-08-10 19:45:41.101 CEST [15565] flaut@flaut_db WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
>
> 2018-08-10 19:45:44.376 CEST [24924] LOG:  statistics collector process (PID 26425) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
>
> 2018-08-10 19:45:44.477 CEST [24924] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
>
> 2018-08-10 19:45:45.237 CEST [15673] flaut@flaut_db FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode

Согласно Nginx Amplify оперативная память ни разу не доходила даже до половины. Открыл htop и там отображается, что занято 690M из 1.91G. За весь день оперативная память ни разу не была исчерпана. С чем связано это падение базы?

Comment: Посмотрите в `dmesg` не приходил ли случайно OOM. И посмотрите что в логах базы до всех `erminating connection because of crash of another server process` - это следствия, база складывается сама, если нештатно был убит любой процесс. Но судя по `terminated by signal 9: Killed` я думаю здесь всё-таки был OOM. Весьма стоит добавить swap, да, OOM может придти когда казалось бы память ещё есть, наблюдал такое.

Comment: `Terminating connection because of crash of another server process` - есть такое. Значит всё же проблема с нехваткой оперативной памяти...

Comment: Я спросил, что есть ДО ВСЕХ таких сообщений. Каждый из backend напишет, что завершается аварийно, но что было причиной этому - было написано в лог ранее.